# In Xcode 4.3, the option of making a UITableviewCell with Interface Builder is gone

Tags: uitableview, interface-builder, xcode4.3

In Xcode 4.3, when creating a new `UITableViewCell`, the option of "With Xib for user interface" is disabled now. Does anyone know how I can create custom cells with IB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create a simple view XIB
2. Drag a table view cell into the XIB from the object browser in the bottom right corner
3. Delete the superfluous view